# iOS: Custom application wide banner with UINavigationController

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin

I would like to have an application wide banner to display custom messages to the user. This banner is not always present, but can be displayed on any screen in the app. When it is displayed, it does not sit on top of the current view, but instead forces the current view to resize below it. The goal is to implement the custom banner only once, and not in every screen.

The approach I have tried is to use a `UINavigationController` with a root `UIViewController` with two container `UIView`s (e.g. ContainerView in IB). The root view controller would then have custom code to control the size of the two container views depending if the status banner is shown or not.

The **problem** is when pushing to the `UINavigationController` it replaces both container views with the new `UIViewController`. Instead, I would like to push into the bottom view container only. Can the `UINavigationController` be configured to use the bottom view only or should is there a better approach?

Here is a mockup:

[image: Navigation controller with custom banner]

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to sub class UINavigationController and implement the logic for resizing there instead of in the root view controller. For example implement a method like:

```
- (void)setShowBanner:(BOOL)show {
    CGRect frame = [self frameForViewControllersWhenShowingBanner:show];

    for (UIViewController *vc in self.viewControllers) {
        vc.view.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

The banner view itself would also be added/removed by this subclassed navigation controller. Of course you can make the method above animated by putting the code within an animation block.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty high-level but I would subclass `UIViewController` (ex: `BanneredViewController`), then have all your view controllers that are pushed onto the navigation controller inherit from `BanneredViewController`.

In `BanneredViewController` you could control the state of the display of this banner, fire layout and constraint update events, etc.... For example you might have methods called:

```
-(void)showBannerWithMessage:(NSString *)message;
-(void)hideBanner;
```

In those methods you would update layout constraints, adjust frames, whatever, to get the effect you want. There's a specific way you would do that depending on whether or not you're supporting AutoLayout. With this approach you keep your banner layout code all in one place and use the subclass as needed, and you avoid having to muck with the internals of the `UINavigationController`.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you need to insert a common super view controller for every base view controller (e.g. UIViewController, UITableViewController, UICollectionViewController, UIPageViewController). Also view controllers need to coordinate when they get pushed/popped to ensure the banner remains shown/hidden. This is not their responsibility. If you don't want to subclass UINavigationController, than it is better to use a category on UIViewController instead of a base class which at least circumvents the first problem.

Comment: You're right, it probably doesn't resolve the case where the user pushes and pops view controllers and the banner needs to remain in the nav without itself pushing and popping.

Answer (score -1):

This is a Swift 3 iOS 10 solution.

Create a `UIView` subclass:

```
class NavigationBannerView: UIView {

    let iconImageView = UIImageView()
    let messageTextLabel = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        backgroundColor = .red

        let iconImage = UIImage(named: "YourImage")
        iconImageView.image = iconImage
        iconImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iconImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        addSubview(iconImageView)

        messageTextLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        messageTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        messageTextLabel.textColor = .white
        addSubview(messageTextLabel)

        iconImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        iconImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
        iconImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -4).isActive = true
        iconImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 26).isActive = true

        messageTextLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: iconImageView.rightAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        messageTextLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        messageTextLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        messageTextLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func fadeInfadeOut(for duration: TimeInterval) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.alpha = 1
        }) { (done) in
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + duration, execute: {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
                    self.alpha = 0
                })
            })
        }
    }
}
```

then create a `UINavigationController` subclass

```
class MyNavigationViewController: UINavigationController {

    var navigationBannerView: NavigationBannerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //BannerView
        navigationBannerView = NavigationBannerView(frame: .zero)
        view.addSubview(navigationBannerView)
        view.bringSubview(toFront: navigationBannerView)

        navigationBannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        navigationBannerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        navigationBannerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        navigationBannerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        navigationBannerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 34).isActive = true
        navigationBannerView.alpha = 0
    }

    func showBanner(with text: String, duration: TimeInterval) {
        navigationBannerView.messageTextLabel.text = text
        navigationBannerView.fadeInfadeOut(for: duration)
    }
}
```

Then you can call on your NavigationController `showBanner(with text: String, duration: TimeInterval)` when ever you need a banner to be shown.